# Can't set key value array to an array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('key' => 'value'),
    array('key' => 'value'),
    array('key' => 'value')
);

foreach($array as $a) {
    $a['anotherkey'] = 'anothervalue';
}
?>
```

I am trying to add another key value ('anotherkey' => 'anothervalue') into each array inside $array. However the above code does not work and I can't seem to figure out why, is it because the $a['anotherkey'] could not add the value to the real array ? And what is the proper way to adding the keyvalue pair into each of the array inside $array using foreach loop ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $array = array(
   array('key' => 'value'),
   array('key' => 'value'),
   array('key' => 'value')
);

foreach($array as &$a) {
  $a['anotherkey'] = 'anothervalue';
}

print_r($array);
```

> Pass By Reference used above. Read here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, it works, thank you so much. I wonder why though, could you care to explain a little bit on the '&' sign and why without it the loop doesn't work ? Thx :)

Comment: @Charas I have added the link above for you. Please go through it. :)

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Charas Glad to help :)

Comment: There's a bug in PHP5/7 make sure you unset($a) after the foreach loop or you can get some funny bugs.

Comment: @JeffreyVanAlstine Thanks for the info.